# what is the BIF to remove an item from a list

Tags: erlang

What is the BIF to remove an item from a list?

Comment: It takes less time to check the `man 3erl lists` than typing your question here. Please make use of manuals for such questions.

Comment: Moreover please provide more details to your question - e.g. what is the criterion for the item to be removed? Is it item's value? Is it it's position?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NewList = CurrentList -- Element` when `Element` is a list

e.g.  `NewList = CurrentList -- [{some_element}]`

Answer (score 11):

If you want to remove a given element, it is [lists:delete/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#delete-2) (which is not a BIF).

If you want to remove an element at a given position, you can do something like:

```
del_nth_from_list(List, N) ->
  {L1, [_|L2]} = lists:split(N-1, List),
  L1 ++ L2.
```

If you want to remove all occurences, then:

```
del_all_occurences(List, Elem) ->
  [E || E <- List, E =/= Elem].
```