# Erlang- Recursive Delete

Tags: recursion, erlang

I am working on writing a recursive function in erlang that given an element X and a list, deletes the element X from the list and returns the new list. I believe I have written it correctly, however, when I run a test on it, I am thrown into an infinite loop..

```
delete(_,[]) -> [];
delete(X,[X|_]) -> [];
delete(X,[Y|YS]) -> 
    if X == Y -> YS;
    true -> [Y] ++ delete(X,[YS]) % I believe the infinite loop is a result of this line..
end.
```

I am very new to erlang (this is my second project using the language), so troubleshooting is a bit difficult for me, but if anyone could provide some guidance, it would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the BIF to remove an item from a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706747/what-is-the-bif-to-remove-an-item-from-a-list)

Comment: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2011-May/058074.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
delete(_,[]) -> []; %% ok removing anything from an empty list gives an empty list
delete(X,[X|_]) -> []; %% big mistake. If you find the element you want to remove on top
                       %% of the list, you must remove it and continue with the rest of the list
delete(X,[Y|YS]) -> 
    if X == Y -> YS;   %% this will never occurs since you already test this case
                       %% in the previous clause. An the result should be delete(X,YS), not YS.
    true -> [Y] ++ delete(X,[YS]) %% correct
end.
```

I don't see where you have an infinite loop, but the second clause will make the recursive calls stop too early.

So your code should be:

```
delete(_,[]) -> [];
delete(X,[X|Rest]) -> delete(X,Rest);
delete(X,[Y|YS]) -> [Y] ++ delete(X,[YS]).
```

but a I would recommend to use list comprehension for a very short code and fast execution (it is the code used in lists:filter/2):

```
delete(X,L) -> [Y || Y <- L, Y =/= X].
%              ^        ^       ^
%              |        |       |_ when Y different from X
%              |        |_________ with all the elements Y from L
%              |__________________ make a list
```

defining the function in the shell, you get:

```
1> D = fun D(_,[]) -> [];       
1>         D(X,[X|R]) -> D(X,R);
1>         D(X,[Y|R]) -> [Y] ++ D(X,R) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.36.90072148>
2> D(4,[1,2,3,4,5,6]).
[1,2,3,5,6]
3> D1 = fun(X,L) -> [Y || Y <- L, Y =/= X] end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.90072148>
4> D1(4,[1,2,3,4,5,6]).                        
[1,2,3,5,6]
5>
```

Comment: In fact, if you are starting with erlang, it is a good idea to write recursive functions since they are everywhere, even if they are often hidden by library functions (lists, dict ... modules r, list or bit string comprehension, gen_server, gen_fsm behaviours ...)

Answer (score 2):

First off, I don't know why you would need the second clause. Basically it's saying "If the first item in the list matches the item to be removed, through the whole list away and return an empty one".

The easiest way to do this is to start with the list and an empty list to store the result. Then as we iterate over the items in the list, we add items that don't match to the result and ignore items that match the item we want deleted. This will remove all occurrences of `X` in `List`:

```
delete(X, List) -> delete(X, List, []). % Provide the same API as before

delete(_,[], Result) -> Result; % If the list is empty we are done.
delete(X,[Y|YS], Result) -> 
  case X == Y of
    true ->
      delete(X,[YS], Result);
    false -> 
      delete(X,[Y|YS], Result)
  end.
```

But why not use `lists:filter/2`? It makes it much simpler:

```
delete(X, List) ->
  lists:filter(fun(Item) ->
    Item /= X
  end, List).
```